# Icons are not seen in DateTimePicker Bootstrap in inline

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using DateTimePicker in Bootstrap3 for the following project : https://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/demo.php
The problem is that when I use the "inline" option I lose the "back" and "forward" icons to navigate the months.

Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Calendar</title>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>

    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <link href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.es.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div id="calendar"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#calendar').datetimepicker({
        language:  'es',
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        weekStart: 1,
        todayBtn:  1,
        autoclose: 1,
        todayHighlight: 1,
        startView: 2,
        minView: 2,
        forceParse: 0
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Try all the available documentation options but I can not make the icons look.

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/drgLsrc2/

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Which datetimepicker are you using from the list there, and could you please provide markup for your datetimepicker?

Comment: https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker

Comment: I ask this because I've noticed in your code above there's no datetimepicker, only the divs. Is that your entire code above?

Comment: Sorry, I'm wrong this is the one I use: https://github.com/AuspeXeu/bootstrap-datetimepicker

Comment: And yes, it is my complete code.

Comment: Post updated with example.

Comment: ok, It's much clearer now.

Comment: Can you try using cdn for your datetimepicker (css /js) instead of using inline.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
  #calendar: right: "glyphicon-chevron-right",
              left: "glyphicon-chevron-left"
```